# Chart.js chart positions variable at 0 even though value is >0

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to display a chart by assigning values to an array that will be referenced in charts data.

For whatever reason the chart registers the value in the Array but does not position the value correctly in the chart. I thought it was something to do with the type of the variable, so I tried casting and parsing to no avail.

What can I do to resolve this?

**Edit1** - I can add and subtract with the JSON variable, so must be something else rather than a type issue.

> Here is my test script

```
                var applied = new Array();
                month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                applied.push(2);
                applied.push(23);
                applied.push(21);
                applied.push(2);
                applied.push(2);
                applied.push(2);
                applied.push(2);
                applied.push(2);
                applied.push(2);
                applied.push(2);
                var json = $.get("../rest/hello?from=01/"+month+"/2018&to=31/"+month+"/2018", function (data){
                    applied.push(parseInt(data);
                    console.log(applied[0]);
                });
```

> Here is my chart script

```
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                              "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
                            ];
                        var chartlabels = new Array();
                        for(var i = 11; i > -1; i--){
                            var date = new Date();
                            date.setMonth(date.getMonth()-i)
                            chartlabels.push(months[date.getMonth()]);
                        }
                            var ctx = document.getElementById("approvedtoemployed");
                            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                                type : 'line',
                                data : {
                                    labels: chartlabels,
                                    datasets : [ {
                                        label : '# of approved',
                                        data : applied,
                                        backgroundColor : [
                                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0)'
                                                ],
                                        borderColor : [ 
                                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                                                ],
                                        borderWidth : 1
                                    }]
                                },
                                options : {
                                    responsive : false,
                                    maintainAspectRatio : false,
                                    legend: {
                                        display: true,
                                        position: 'bottom',
                                        boxWidth: '15'
                                    },
                                }
                            });
```

[image: Chart image]

[image: Chart image with 12 values in dataset]

Comment: On your chart screenshot there's no dot positioned on zero y-axis. All your values except 23 and 21 are 2.

Comment: Value seems to be <2 between april and may is caused by bezier curve smoothing, try setting line tension to zero

Comment: On the screenshot the tooltip says `November [] # of approved :34` this value is positioned at zero on y-axis. @ElijahEllanski

Comment: It's cause you have 12 months and only 10 values in dataset

Comment: @ElijahEllanski with all due respect, it isn't. No matter if the dataset equals the amount of labels or not, output is exactly the same, point sits at zero on y-axis. Screenshot to follow. And also there are 11 values in the dataset.

Comment: Unrelated but why don't you use an immediate array for "applied"? Seems pretty roundabout to use "new" and push a bunch of stuff.

Comment: It's different screenshots with nonequal datasets. However you should pass same dots quantity on y-axis as on x, try to set empty values to null. And maybe you'll have to set `spanGaps: true`

Answer (score 0):

Issue must sit with how and when JSON data is loaded.

The chart has to be built within the `$.get` method, once this is done the chart maps variable correctly.